# Changer style Browser.msgBox / Change style Browser.msgBox

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a create a code that manages the inventory of a fleet, and it works well.

I would like to know if it is possible to "beautify" the Browser.msgBox that are displayed if there is an error.

I looked on a lot of posts, but I can not find. Is it possible to do it?

```
function validation() {

var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var s = ss.getSheetByName('Flotte');
var values = s.getDataRange().getValues();
var values1 = s.getDataRange().getValues();
var choix = s.getRange("B5").getValue();
var nbr = s.getRange("E5").getValue();
var vaisseauSuppr = s.getRange("C5").getValue();
var vaisseauPlus = s.getRange("D5").getValue();
var nbrOrigin = s.getRange("E5").getValue();
var lr = s.getLastRow() + 1;
var lc = s.getLastColumn();

var present = false;
var addition = false;

// Si le produit n'est pas défini, on bloque tout de suite l'execution 

if (choix.replace(' ', '') == "") {
    Browser.msgBox("Veuillez choisir une action !");
}
    if (nbr == "") {
        Browser.msgBox("Veuillez définir un nombre en E5 !");
    }

// Sinon, on fait l'opération
else {
  for( var row = values.length -1; row >=6 ; --row ) {
    // Gestion de la suppression
    if(choix == "Supprimer") {
      if (values[row][3] == vaisseauSuppr) {
        if (nbrOrigin < values[row][4]) {

          var result = values[row][4] - nbrOrigin;
          s.getDataRange().getCell(row + 1, 5).setValue(result);
          s.getRange("C5:E5").clearDataValidations();
          s.getRange("B5:E5").clearContent();
          break;

        }
        else {
          s.getRange("C5:E5").clearDataValidations();
          s.getRange("B5:E5").clearContent();
          s.deleteRow(parseInt(row)+1);
        }
      }
    }
    // Gestion de l'addition 
    else {
      addition = true;

      if (values[row][3] == vaisseauPlus) {
        var resultPlus = values[row][4] + nbrOrigin;
        s.getDataRange().getCell(row + 1, 5).setValue(resultPlus);
        s.getRange("C5:E5").clearDataValidations();
        s.getRange("B5:E5").clearContent();
        present = true;
        break;
      }
    }
  }
}

// Dans le cas où le vaisseau n'est pas présent, et qu'il s'agit d'une addition, on ajoute une ligne. 
if (addition && !present) {
  var lienRsi = s.getRange(lr, 2);

  s.getRange("C5:E5").clearDataValidations();
  s.getRange("B5:E5").clearContent();
  s.getRange(lr, 3).setValue(vaisseauSuppr);
  s.getRange(lr, 4).setValue(vaisseauPlus);

  //Affichage du lien de page RSI :
lienRsi.setFormula('=HYPERLINK(query(IFERROR(IMPORTRANGE(importrange("xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx";"Données changeables!h3");UPPER("Bd vaisseaux!$f$6:$q"));importrange(importrange("xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx";"Données changeables!h3");LOWER("Bd vaisseaux!$f$6:$q")));"select Col12 where (Col1=\''+vaisseauPlus+'\')");"Caractéristiques")');

s.getRange(lr, 5).setValue(nbrOrigin);
}    

// Trie de la plage de données :
var tri = s.getRange(9, 2, lr-1, 4);

tri.sort([{column: 3, ascending:true},{column: 4, ascending:true}]);
```

Comment: What is it that you want to change on it? Have you checked the [docs](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/base/browser#msgBox(String,String,ButtonSet))? Maybe you want to try [dialogs](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/dialogs) instead.

Comment: @HenriqueG.Abreu, i would like of possible to change text color and add a picture in it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If by "beautify" you mean changing text style or other things in the popup body, you can achieve that by using `HtmlService` on a custom dialog. Check out its docs [here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/dialogs#custom_dialogs).

Comment: I'm going to see this solution, thank you @HenriqueG.Abreu